# Rails 3 and Communityengine Photo Uploads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, imagemagick, paperclip, communityengine

I got my rails application using Communityengine up and running now, but somehow I can't make the image uploads work.

In the standard installation I would always get this error when I try to upload an image:

```
Photo /tmp/stream20130319-18602-13k89ab.gif is not recognized by the 'identify' command.
```

Imagemagick is correctly installed and the identify-command works. The permissions to the /tmp/ folder are correct, too. So I am clueless with this issue =(.

To work around this issue I tried to use Amazon S3 for storage since I don't mind where the images come from (See [here](https://github.com/bborn/communityengine)). I copied the correctly filled out s3.yml to the applications /config/ folder. I am using gem "aws-sdk" in my Gemfile as suggested here: [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/storage/s3.rb); and I updated application_config.rb like this:

```
:photo => {
    :missing_thumb => '/assets/icon_missing_thumb.gif',
    :missing_medium => "/assets/icon_missing_medium.gif",
    :paperclip_options => {
      :storage => 's3',
      :styles => {
        :thumb => {
          :geometry => '100x66#',
          :processors => [:cropper]
        },
        :medium => {
          :geometry => '300x200#',
          :processors => [:cropper]
        },
        :large => {
          :geometry => '600x400#',
          :processors => [:cropper]
        },   
        :original => "1024>"       
      }
    },
    :validation_options => {
      :max_size => 3,
      :content_type => ['image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/gif', 'image/png', 'image/x-png']          
    }
  },

  :feature => {
    :use_thumbs => true,
    :paperclip_options => {
      :storage => 's3',
      :styles => {
        :thumb => "100x66#",
        :medium => '300x200#',
        :large => "600x400#",
        :original => '1024>'             
      }
    },
    :validation_options => {
      :max_size => 3,
      :content_type => ['image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/gif', 'image/png', 'image/x-png']          
    }
  },

  :clipping => {
    :paperclip_options => {
      :storage => 's3',
      :styles => {
        :thumb => "100x66#",
        :medium => "300x200#",
        :large => "600x400#",
        :original => '1024>'     
      }
    },
    :validation_options => {
      :max_size => 3,
      :content_type => ['image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/gif', 'image/png', 'image/x-png']              
    }
  },
```

When I try to edit a user profile or upload an image I get this error: 
uninitialized constant AWS::S3::Base
Full Trace here:

```
 paperclip (2.4.5) lib/paperclip/storage/s3.rb:101:in `block in extended'
paperclip (2.4.5) lib/paperclip/storage/s3.rb:79:in `instance_eval'
paperclip (2.4.5) lib/paperclip/storage/s3.rb:79:in `extended'
paperclip (2.4.5) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:392:in `extend'
paperclip (2.4.5) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:392:in `initialize_storage'
paperclip (2.4.5) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:73:in `initialize'
paperclip (2.4.5) lib/paperclip.rb:448:in `new'
paperclip (2.4.5) lib/paperclip.rb:448:in `attachment_for'
paperclip (2.4.5) lib/paperclip.rb:337:in `block in has_attached_file'
activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:85:in `block in assign_attributes'
activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:78:in `each'
activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:78:in `assign_attributes'
activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/base.rb:497:in `initialize'
/home/martin/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/communityengine-281d49916dbc/app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:104:in `new'
/home/martin/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/communityengine-281d49916dbc/app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:104:in `create'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:460:in `block (2 levels) in _run__141873283__process_action__116704501__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:215:in `block in _conditional_callback_around_1705'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:326:in `around'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:310:in `_callback_around_1685'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:214:in `_conditional_callback_around_1705'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:459:in `block in _run__141873283__process_action__116704501__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:215:in `block in _conditional_callback_around_1704'
/home/martin/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/communityengine-281d49916dbc/lib/community_engine/localized_application.rb:25:in `set_locale'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:214:in `_conditional_callback_around_1704'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run__141873283__process_action__116704501__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:601:in `call'
rakismet (1.3.0) lib/rakismet/middleware.rb:10:in `call'
omniauth (1.1.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:177:in `call!'
omniauth (1.1.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:157:in `call'
omniauth (1.1.2) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__284061703__call__288038654__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Can anyone help me here? I am really stuck with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue now!
The Jquery-Bootstrap branch of CommunityEngine uses paperclip 2.4.5 and this issue is resolved in newer Versions.

I forked Communityengine on Github and updated the paperclip dependency to 2.7.4. 
Just replace this in `community_engine.gemspec`:

```
s.add_dependency(%q<paperclip>, ["~> 2.4.3"])
```

with this:

```
s.add_dependency(%q<paperclip>, ["~> 2.7.4"])
```

Another issue was that newer versions required "bucket" instead of "bucket_name" in the S3 credentials (which I messed up this way).

Answer (score 1):

Paperclip 2.4.5 still uses the aws-s3 gem.

Change your Gemfile line to:

```
gem "aws-s3", :require => "aws/s3"
```

or use the master branch instead of the stable version (which of course has some risk involved):

```
gem 'paperclip', :git => "git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git"
gem "aws-sdk"
```

**UPDATE:** Paperclip 2.5.0, released on 1/13/2012, now uses aws-sdk

**For you second problem am updating this answer**

The primary issue is that you need to move the following code into it's own initializer file:

```
if Rails.env == "production" 
   S3_CREDENTIALS = { :access_key_id => ENV['S3_KEY'], :secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET'], :bucket => "ourbucket"} 
 else 
   S3_CREDENTIALS = Rails.root.join("config/s3.yml")
end
```

Then, you should add the following line to your model where you have *has_attached_file :photo* The line to add is.

```
:s3_credentials => S3_CREDENTIALS,
```

This is what you were missing before.

Also, for when you declare your bucket name, make sure that is for standard us. If you use one of the other locations, you'll have to update the path appropriately.

Hope this helps!

Comment: When I change this I get a different error: "Credentials are not a path, file, or hash". Thrown by this line "= image_tag( @user.avatar_photo_url(:medium), :class => "thumbnail" )" and the trace looks similar: "paperclip (2.4.5) lib/paperclip.rb:332:in `block in has_attached_file'
/home/martin/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/communityengine-281d49916dbc/app/models/user.rb:260:in `avatar_photo_url'"

Comment: I upvoted it, but I cant accept it since this was not the issue that solved my problem. Thanks though for your effort!